# Silverstripe Text Parser Function not returning value

Tags: php, silverstripe

Can someone please help troubleshoot my TextParser function which checks to see if the variable $SubTitle on my page template contains the word "Hire" and either display or hide a div block accordingly.

When $SubTitle does contain the word "Hire" the function is not returning visible. I assume it's something to do with $str = $SubTitle but not sure how to correctly write this??

---

```
class OrderTypeExtension extends TextParser
{
   function parse(){
   $str = $SubTitle;

   if (strpos($str, 'Hire') !== false)
   return 'visible';
   else return 'hidden';

   }
}
```

Comment: No offense, but your code lets me believe you're quite new to SilverStripe and programming in general. I'm sure there's a better solution than using the `TextParser` for this… is `SubTitle` a field on your Page?

Comment: No offence taken. I've been getting more familiar with it over the past 12 months but still very green with functions and trying to extend the basics.

SubTitle refers to a variable part of the OrderItem info on the cart page of the site. Not sure how to best explain but the function is below.

public function SubTitle()
    { 
        return 'Hire: '. $this->Lease()->Title; /* ' ($'. $this->Lease()->PricePerLength. '/mth)' */
    }

Comment: Are you using silvershop? Is that a custom OrderItem class where you implemented that `SubTitle` function, or how did you add it? From the information you provided, it seems like `SubTitle` would always contain the string `Hire`. I think you should add some more information to your questions to make it answerable at all.

Comment: Yes using silvershop. There are two different OrderItem modules from what I can see (Hireable and Used). Hireable $SubTitle function appends 'Hire:' to the order item details and Used appends 'Buy:' to the order item. 

So I was assuming that with $Content.Parse(OrderTypeExtension) I could check whether the text 'Hire:' is displayed in any $SubTitle variable on the cart.ss page

Apologies in advance that I can't be clearer. I don't even know half the time whether I'm using the correct terminology but I appreciate you trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

If you're implementing the `OrderItem` subclasses yourself, you can just add a helper method to each one, with:

```
public function getVisibility()
{
    return strpos($this->SubTitle, 'Hire') === false ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
}
```

Or, if these `OrderItem` classes are coming from a module and should be left untouched, use an `Extension`.

```
class VisibilityExtension extends Extension
{
    public function getVisibility()
    {
        return strpos($this->owner->SubTitle, 'Hire') === false 
            ? 'hidden' : 'visible';
    }
}
```

Then add the `VisibilityExtension` to your `OrderItem` classes, [as described in the docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/3/developer_guides/extending/extensions/).

After a `dev/build` you can use `$Visibility` in your template to either output `hidden`, or `visible`.

Comment: Thanks @bummzack I've implemented the code and it looks like the extension is rendering okay as its replacing $getVisibility with 'hidden' in the cart.ss template but when a hire product is added it doesn't change to 'visible' so I assume something with the $this->owner->Subtitle isn't checking the orderItem correctly.

I've added the files to github if you want to still help (https://github.com/FarrowDesign/ff_shop)

The SubTitle function that we are trying to check is in LeaseOrderItem.php

Comment: See, this is why StackOverflow encourages you to write the problem you're trying to solve and what you did so far in your question. Without the problem, it's really hard to give a good answer. Your problem is: _How can I hide information in the cart template when some type of item is in the cart?_, not about the TextParser at all.

Comment: I don't think this question/answer can be salvaged… I encourage you to create a new question and maybe delete this one.